# How to get Field value and pass it to FieldArray value with Push event? Redux-Form V6-RC3

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I have a FieldArray component supposed to show telephones.
The user can add a telephone object containing a number Field, a type Field and a button to add the phone into the phone list(FieldArray).

The Phone List component contains a button with the function fields.remove(index) which I pass the phone index to.

**My phone object is:** {number: number, type: type}

**Currently using:** React 0.15.3, Redux-Form 6.0.0-rc3, Material-UI 0.15.3

**Phone fields declaration:**

```
<Field name="phoneNumber" component={renderMaskedTextField} label={"Telefone"} type="text" mask="(99) 9999-99999"/>

<Field name="phoneType" component={renderSelectField} label="Tipo">
      {PHONE_TYPES.map((option, index) => {
        return <MenuItem value={option.value} primaryText={option.label} key={index}/>;
      })}
</Field>
```

**Code I use to add the phone component into the list:**

```
<IconButton onClick={() => handleAddClick({number: field.input.phone.number, type: field.input.phone.type})} style={styles.addButton}>
   <Add color="#fd084a"/>
</IconButton>
```

**I need a way to get both Field values and pass it to my *handleAddClick()***

Add function:

```
const handleAddClick = (phone) => {
   fields.push(phone);
};
```

**Also open to new ways to solve this :D**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`arrayPush()` action creator](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/#-arraypush-form-string-field-string-value-any-). Then all you'll need to figure out is how to get `dispatch` or to pre-bind the action creator in `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
import { arrayPush } from 'redux-form'

@connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { arrayPush }
)
class MyForm extends Component {

  ...

  handleAddClick(phone) {
    this.props.arrayPush('myForm', 'phones', phone)
  }

  ...
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Erik, but my component is not inside my form directly, it comes from a wrapper I have for Material-UI components. The phone Field is inside the FieldArray component, and FieldArray is inside my form component. I don't have access to mapStateToProps on this material-UI wrapper

Comment: With the imported action creator you can do it from _any_ component, as long as you know the form and field names, because all you have to do is use `connect()` to get `dispatch` and then you can `dispatch(arrayPush())`.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a try then. Thank you a lot, I was having a real bad time trying to figure a way out.